# Problem with calling a function via a function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have a struct with a function pointer, that is intended for pointing to the bar() function, but i have no clue how to call the function that's being pointed on:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Foo
{
  int (*func_ptr)(const char *, const char *);
} Foo;

int bar(const char *a, const char *b)
{
  return 3;
}

int main(void)
{
  Foo *foo = (Foo *)malloc(sizeof(Foo));
  foo->func_ptr = &bar;
  //how do i call the function?
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: (*foo->func_ptr)("hel", "lo");

Comment: @kaylum yes, it does answer my question, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine your `const char *a` is "hello" and `const char *b` is "there", then you can use any of the following forms to call the function by its pointer:

```
  (foo->func_ptr)("hello", "there");
  (*foo->func_ptr)("hello", "there");
  foo->func_ptr("hello", "there");
```